# Find tables+rows restraining a delete

Tags: mysql, doctrine, foreign-keys

We have a fairly large database, set up via Symfony+Doctrine, which has been in the running for a while. Some of those entities are made with SoftDeletableTrait at the time. Some of those entities no longer required softdelete so we're going to delete the rows with a 'deletedAt' value and then drop the SoftDeletableTrait.

We need to find which tables/rows are referenced currently, example:

```
TableA
ID   name  deleted_at
1    Foo   NULL
2    Bar   01-01-2020 10:11:12
```

I want all tables and rows referencing to TableA id=2:

```
TableFoo id=19
TableFoo id=21
TableBar id=7
```

If it where one table, we could do an subquery or join to complare it with one other table, but we dont know the amount of other tables.
We Could check the entity and see all it's references, but TableA isn't the only table getting scrubbed, there are about 10 large tables, so we're looking for a (semi-)automatic method.